# C# Winforms Listview - How can you take programmatic control of the up and down arrow keys on the keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I haven't been working with winforms for many moons and when I was, it was in Visual Basic. Anyways, I have a ListView control and I understand that this control handles the up and down arrows from the keyboard internally, but I really need to have more control over the behavior of these keys when they are pressed.

Let's say we have a list of items > A, B, C, D, E, F, G

The main issue here is someone can highlight a selection in the list of items on my ListView with the mouse. For example, A. If they hold the left mouse button down and drag the cursor to another item (for example, F) and release, the item that the cursor is over is selected. Not a problem. This opens up a dialog box, they do their work and when the dialog box closes, they are brought back to the list and the item they selected is highlighted (F is still highlighted). Again, not a problem. The problem is if once returning to the ListView they use the up or down arrow keys to navigate the list. Let's say they hit the down arrow key once. At this point, because they were originally on A when they dragged the mouse down to F, B highlights. So even though F was properly selected, the ListView still thinks that A was the last item selected and it will jump back to that selection if the up or down arrows are used.

I've done a lot of hunting around and there are various snippets of code to do this and that with the ListView control (or some other control or the Form in general) and capturing keyboard presses, but nothing really coherent, at least from a "Start to Finish" example. Can someone provide some insight? If you start discussing delegates or creating an event handler, etc., all I ask is that you please go into enough detail so I can figure out what you are talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyPress event.

[ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Event Handler Declaration

```
this.listView1.KeyPress += listView1_keyDown;
```

In the event handler you can do something similar to:

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
             //Change Last Selected Item
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And add the additional logic you need.

Also Consider the selected index changed event:

```
this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Additional Thoughts:
Make sure Multi line select is disabled.  Not sure if this applies to you but if this is enabled then you could be selecting the A and selecting F correctly however A would come first in displaying the logic after.  If your code isn't expecting more than 1 selected item this could also be the cause.

```
this.listView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Russ...I will check out your suggestion and see if that will work.

Comment: These are the following I have in the InitializeComponent() within my ListContentsDialog.Designer.cs:

         this.listView1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listView1_MouseUp);
         this.listView1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listView1_MouseMove);
         this.listView1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listView1_MouseDown);
         this.listView1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.listView1_KeyPress);

OnKeyPress is not available?

Comment: JimB you want the KeyPress Event.  My mistake I've updated my answer.